# How to prevent WordPress update notification from being displayed in plugin admin page?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Tried add those to main php file of plugin, did not help:

I would also prevent any other notification.

```php
function tiketwp_handle_php_errors()
{
    // Turn off the display of PHP errors
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);

    // Log PHP errors to a file
    ini_set('log_errors', 1);
    ini_set('error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/php_errors.log');

    // Set the error reporting level
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
}

function disable_plugin_update_notification() {
    remove_action('admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3);
}

add_action('init', 'TiketWP\\twppwr\\tiketwp_handle_php_errors');
add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_plugin_update_notification');
```

[image]

---

I tried now add a style like this:

```
.notice {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to disable all of these notifications, or just a specific one?

Comment: The image you post does not show any update notification. So why did you post this image?

Comment: Yes, this is example for all the other notifications

Comment: The short answer is that you can't disable all notifications because many plugins have decided to write their own implementation. You might be able to get some, however, and `!important` might help in your CSS. In the long term, which I know isn't helpful for you right now, WordPress has been thinking about this for many years and has finally [put something together](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/04/25/wp-feature-notifications-2023-status-update/) to address it hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

This is a notorious problem. But concealing all notices is **dangerous** -- they are the way core and plugin developers communicate with site owners, and they sometimes include security alerts. Read this for more information. https://freemius.com/blog/wordpress-admin-notices/ And don't hide your notices or you will be sorry. If some plugins put up notices you can't dismiss, complain to the plugin developer.